# Why imperfect subjunctive?

Tags: subjuntivo

Estoy estudiando el subjuntivo en este momento, y trato averiguar los siguientes:

1. ¿por qué utilizaría el autór el subjuntivo de imperfecto en este pasaje, en vez de la condicional?
2. ¿cuál sería el “trigger” de subjuntivo en esta frase?

“No podía dejar de hacerlo, de buscar la chispa que **despertara** mi inspiración, de trazar una trama que me **devolviera** a ser el centro de atención.”

¡Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: It is because it is hypothetical whether the thing searched for exists.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La diferencia entre usar el potencial (o condicional) y el pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo en la subordinada cuando el verbo de la proposición principal:

- No **podía** dejar de ...

está en pasado radica en que el potencial equivale al futuro desde una perspectiva pasada y, por lo tanto, expresa certeza:

- **Sabía** que había una chispa que **despertaría** mi inspiración y que había una trama que me **devolvería** al  centro de atención ("devolver a ser" no me parece ni gramatical ni semánticamente correcto), y no podía dejar de buscar la chispa que **despertaría** mi inspiración y la trama que me **devolvería** al  centro de atención. (La forma en presente sería: No puedo dejar de buscar la chispa que despertará ... y la trama que me devolverá..., PERO SÉ O CREO QUE EN ALGÚN MOMENTO OCURRIRÁ)

En cambio, el pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo es la forma pasada del presente del subjuntivo, y por lo tanto expresa duda:

- **Dudaba** que hubiera una chispa que **despertara** mi inspiración y que hubiera una trama que me **devolviera** al  centro de atención, pero aun así no podía dejar de buscar la chispa que **despertara** mi inspiración y la trama que me **devolviera** al  centro de atención. (La forma en presente sería: No puedo dejar de buscar la chispa que despierte ... y la trama que me devuelva... PERO NO SÉ SI ESA CHISPA Y ESA TRAMA EXISTEN)

Note: If you prefer the answer in English, just let me know.

Comment: I get it now…thanks so much! Makes total sense. Very helpful.